# ANTLR4 Listener "different context" issue with labels

Tags: listener, antlr, antlr4

I have a problem with my listener :

- I am using a **ParseTreeProperty** to store "anything" (it is basically a Map< ParserRuleContext,MyObject >): *private ParseTreeProperty< MyObject > parseTreeProperty;*
- I store the variable in the **enterEveryRule** method : *parseTreeProperty.put(ctx, myObject);*
- I get it back on the **exitEveryRule** method : *MyObject myObject = parseTreeProperty.get(ctx);*

**This works perfectly, except with labels.**

Any grammar with labels :

```
general_rule
    : rule_1    #label_1
    | rule_2    #label_2
    ;
```

Problem :

- when the listener enters the method *enterEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx)*, the context ctx is **General_ruleContext**.
- when the listener enters the method *exitEveryRule(ParserRuleContext ctx)*, the context ctx is **Label_1Context**/**Label_2Context**.

Since **the context is different between the enterEveryRule and exitEveryRule**, **the ParseTreeProperty doesn't work as intended with labels**. 
Why isn't the entering context the "label rule" or the exiting context the "main rule" ?

How can I solve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, in the generated listener, the results of the tree walk walker alternatives of "general_rule" will be in the same `enterGeneral_rule()` and `exitGeneral_rule()` methods.

But with the labels that you're using the methods will be like:

```
void enterLabel_1();
void exitLabel_1();
void enterLabel_2();
void exitLabel_2();
```